# Questions without accepted answers and left for months as such flummoxes people.

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

I found that many newcomers , come , ask question, for which they get a number of answers . But they don't care about accepting an answer . My doubt is , is there not even a single answer that is acceptable ? . ok there might be chances for that . But the way they communicate with people who answered (in the comment section) with words like " Thanks " " yes I was searching for this answer only " and so on , makes me feel that they are satisfied with that answer at least. But still they don't accept answers . If they have a reason why they haven't accepted answers , they should let others know what they actually expect , so that they get the answers they want . Even this is missing .

What should we do in such a case ?

1) Is it right to comment below their question as a reminder for them to accept an answer and close as it perplexes people who later search and come to such questions .Or will such a comment be considered silly ?

2) Is there not a need for the site to send such reminders . Because this can help them in case they have forgotten it .

3) Or is there a need to give rights to some very top reputation users to do this . Because except in some cases ,in all other case everyone knows that an answer is 100 % right .

Please clarify .

Above all , one thing which I am sure about is "questions with 0 unaccepted answers , flummoxes users who search answers for a similar question ."

Comment: About your question 1: There is even a [comment template](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/4945#4945) for this. Of course, we should not overuse it.

Comment: Once upon a time, each users "accept rate" was on display, and at least for repeat users one could post reminders about the virtues of accepting answers. But this feature was scuttled some time ago. It wouldn't help with the drive-by users, anyway.

Comment: Oh is it ? I was expecting such a feature . Because if the "accept rate " is very very low , why should he paid much attention , because there is more probability that his questions have no end (no accepted answers ) . It is understandable in cases where questions are really perplexing.But these are negligible. Even in that case the O.P . must clarify why he did not accept answers .

Comment: "... these are negligible." Please, take a look at the fact that over 10 percent of the questions does not have **any** answers, hence most definitely cannot have an accepted answer. Not to mention the host of questions where a good answer is lacking (together these more or less constitute the 15 percent share of Unanswered questions); admittedly, this is often partly due to the question being of suboptimal quality, but such is beside the point. I'm glad that the accept rate is not on public display any more.

Comment: In my experience the askers don't have a *reason* for not accepting answers. They are simply not aware that accepting answers is a thing one can do in the first place; they think of the site as just a message board. Anyway, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) is the relevant help article that you can link them to.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the phenomenon has been already discussed a lot, and my own perception of it changed considerably over time.

1. I would not consider such a comment silly at all, although it is a bit better when it is made not by one of the answerers.
2. As you say yourself, most of these cases come from one-day one-question users, and for them automatic reminders will have almost no effect. (Of course there are exceptions, including askers with hundreds of questions that have been here for years, but they are in my opinion negligible).
3. I would be strongly opposed to that. Green mark bonus is not intended to attest correctness of the answer (for that we have votes, comments, and alternative answers) but its appreciation by the asker. That's why accepted answer is not always the best - quite often it can be even completely wrong.

Comment: Thanks . But with regard to your comment 2 ,by new comers I also mean people with 50 or 60 reputations . To know if they were ever seen after they received answers , I normally go to their profile pages and see when they were last seen . Surprisingly they were seen after they have received many answers .So in that case its bad they don't respond after getting answers .How to check this ? Does this not bring disgrace to answers service , if they are neglected ? I believe this would even discourage them . Correct me if I am wrong .